# how many times do we have to choose to remove all the edges from the entire graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Given the complete graph on 16 vertices $K_{16}$, if we choose 8 vertices at a time, and remove all the edges <s>from</s> that connect between those vertices, at least how many times do we have to choose to remove all the edges from the entire graph?

Comment: Sounds like two times...

Comment: Uh, two? Am I missing something? This seems completely trivial.

Comment: @Matt: Unless the OP means that an edge is removed iff **both** ends are in the chosen set of $8$.

Comment: Oh I see. Then the answer is at least 5, but maybe more.

Comment: Guys! Isn't removing just one vertex to which 15 edges are connected solves the problem by just one choice?

Comment: @Asemismaiel: Not on either possible interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @BrianScott Kindly further explain.

Comment: @Asemismaiel: Your suggestion removes only $15$ edges on one interpretation and no edges on the other.

Comment: I think the answer is 18. You can remove two entire disjoint complete graphs on 8 vertices, then you have a complete bipartite graph on 16 vertices left. I think it takes 16 moves to get rid of those edges.

Comment: Are you asking for the minimum number of $K_8$ subgraphs (not necessarily disjoint) that we can combine to produce a $K_{16}$?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system Here you're looking at $S(2,8,16)$

Comment: Not 18! 6! It only takes four moves to kill the bipartite graph. That's almost the best you can do (5 is the absolute minimum). Maybe you can do 5 some more clever way.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I think you were thinking it was $16$ on each side?  Then it would take $16$ further $K_8$.

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's what I was thinking. But it's only 8 on each side.

Comment: can anyone prove that it is impossible to get rid of all the edges in 5 steps?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 6 times.

First you choose any 8 vertices and you remove all the edges that connect those vertices. Then you take the other 8 vertices and also remove their edges. At this point you have a bipartite graph, $K_{8,8}$, and you have done 2 choices.

Now you choose any four vertices from one side and four from the other and remove their edges. Then you choose the other four vertices from one side and the other four from the other side and remove the edges. In this step you have done 4 choices and you have 2 bipartite graphs $K_{4,4}$.

Finally, you do two more choices to remove the edges of each $K_{4,4}$.

Comment: This proves 6 is an upper bound, but is it the lowest possible?

Comment: I think it does because you're choosing vertices with a "maximum" number of edges. But let me think, It's necessary a better argument.